# Cannot install phantomjs -- Is it a bitbucket issue?

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs

phantomjs fails to install. Does the error indicate that bitbucket has a problem?

```
$ sudo npm install -g phantomjs
...
> phantomjs@1.9.7-6 install /usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Looks like an `npm install -g`; unable to check for already installed version.
Downloading http://cdn.bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Saving to /usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Receiving...
Error requesting archive.
Status: 403
Request options: {
  "protocol": "http:",
  "slashes": true,
  "auth": null,
  "host": "cdn.bitbucket.org",
  "port": null,
  "hostname": "cdn.bitbucket.org",
  "hash": null,
  "search": null,
  "query": null,
  "pathname": "/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2",
  "path": "/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2",
  "href": "http://cdn.bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2"
}
Response headers: {
  "content-type": "application/xml",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "date": "Fri, 23 May 2014 13:29:01 GMT",
  "server": "AmazonS3",
  "x-cache": "Error from cloudfront",
  "via": "1.1 73a3bce79e63d88b3a25c9ced0be16f5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
  "x-amz-cf-id": "V06j38N_5EE5K5vPU1uj8ADZ7451C7zTZ-rqsn785PFU-6Sxu-KfiQ=="
}
Make sure your network and proxy settings are correct.
npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.7-6 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.7-6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-61-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phantomjs"
npm ERR! cwd /home/phil
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/phil/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE: It has been fixed, but you have to upgrade phantomjs**

Source: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/178

Some background: I ran into the same problem again on MacOS because it did not upgrade all `package.json` files.

Also note that there are two phantomjs projects:

1. https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs (the main project)
2. https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs (NPM wrapper for installing phantomjs)

The fix for the download issues concerns the npm wrapper.

---

(Here comes my original post)

```
$ wget http://cdn.bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
2014-05-23 15:41:41 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I send an email to the maintainer (as suggested by the npm error message). Now, I think, we just have to sit it out.

Update: github issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12260

Answer (score 20):

Setting `PHANTOMJS_CDNURL` as mentioned on the [phantom js npm page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantomjs) seems to work as a workaround.

```
PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads
npm install phantomjs
```

Comment: I had trouble with the host cnpmjs.org but was able to get the zip linked from here http://phantomjs.org/download.html and substitute the host

Comment: It is still a valuable workaround and it helped me a lot. However, I now switched to my updated answer as the accepted one. The reason is that the issue is now fixed upstream, but you can still run into it if you use an old version of the NPM wrapper for phantomjs. In that case, it is best to upgrade first before falling back to your solution if needed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get a 407 on http://cnpmjs.org/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip

Comment: To be more specific for Mac/Linux, do this in your `~/.bash_profile` or put it in any shell script executed before `npm install`:  `export PHANTOMJS_CDNURL="http://cnpmjs.org/downloads"`

Comment: You can add `ENV PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads` in a Dockerfile to solve it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

See on https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs **Building and Installing**

**Update: before do anything try `npm update`**

```
export PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://cnpmjs.org/downloads npm install phantomjs
npm install -g phantomjs
```

The "npm install phantomjs" is required at the end of the export.

**Maybe you get the error again,** so run `npm update` After all you can run e.g. `karma start test/karma.conf.js`

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround, you can use an alternative installation.

http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and resolved it by updating the npm.